# Plotting solution to PDE is cutting off $ z $-axis

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d

I am trying to plot the solution of a system of coupled PDEs however the result keeps on chopping off the z axis and I am not sure how to display the entire Z axis. How can I show the entire solution that is not cut off by the Z axis? The solution is giving the following result: [image]

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
eps = 0.1
A = 2
eq = {
 
I*D[u1[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u1[t, x], {x, 2}] + u6[t,x]+u2[t,x] == 0, 
I*D[u2[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u2[t, x], {x, 2}] + u1[t,x]+u3[t,x]  == 0,
I*D[u3[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u3[t, x], {x, 2}] + u2[t,x]+u4[t,x] == 0,
I*D[u4[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u4[t, x], {x, 2}] + u3[t,x]+u5[t,x]  == 0,
I*D[u5[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u5[t, x], {x, 2}] + u4[t,x]+u6[t,x]  == 0,
I*D[u6[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u6[t, x], {x, 2}] + u5[t,x]+u1[t,x] == 0,

u1[0, x]  == (eps *A)/Sqrt[3] *Sech[eps*A *(x)],
u2[0, x] == (eps *A)/Sqrt[3] *Sech[eps*A *(x)],
u3[0, x] == (eps *A)/Sqrt[3] *Sech[eps*A *(x)],
u4[0, x] == (eps *A)/Sqrt[3] *Sech[eps*A *(x)],
u5[0, x] == (eps *A)/Sqrt[3] *Sech[eps*A *(x)],
u6[0, x] == (eps *A)/Sqrt[3] *Sech[eps*A* (x)],

a = 150;
u1[t, -a] == u1[t, a], u2[t, -a] == u2[t, a], 
   u3[t, -a] == u3[t, a], u4[t, -a] == u4[t, a], 
   u5[t, -a] == u5[t, a], u6[t, -a] == u6[t, a]

};
var = {u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6};
sol = NDSolve[eq,var, {t, 0,2}, {x, -150, 150},MaxStepSize->0.05];
Table[Plot3D[
  Evaluate[Abs[var[[i]][t, x]] /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 2}, {x, -a, a}, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> var[[i]]], {i, Length[var]}]
```

Comment: Try putting option `PlotRange -> All` in `Plot3D`.